# R igraph: how to find the largest community?

Tags: r, igraph

I use fastgreedy.community to generate a community object, which contains 15 communities. But how can I extract the largest community among these 15 communities?

```
Community sizes
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14 
1862 1708  763  974 2321 1164  649 1046    2    2    2    2    2    2 
15 
2
```

In this example, I want to extract the community 5 for further use.
Thanks!

Comment: `membership(community.object)` tells which community each vertex is in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your community object is named `community.object`, `which(membership(community.object) == x)` extracts the indices of the vertices in community `x`. If you want the largest, community, you can set `x` to `which.max(sizes(community.object))`. Finally, you can use `induced.subgraph` to extract that particular community into a separate graph:

```
> x <- which.max(sizes(community.object))
> subg <- induced.subgraph(graph, which(membership(community.object) == x))
```

Comment: Thanks. But for igraph 0.6 or higher, should use induced.subgraph instead of subgraph

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. Fixed that in my answer.